# Load from gallery function on Android - Sometimes fails, Why?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-gallery

I'm using a `loadfromgallery` function to load and crop an image from gallery, 
but sometimes it doesn't works.

It seems to don't work on devices without SDCard (I tested it on various devices, in my i9000+CM10.1+semaphore with and w/out always works, in a tablet with android>4.0 doesn't works)

Can somebody help me?

This is my `onActivityResult` method:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
            if (imageReturnedIntent!=null){
                getTempFile();
                String filePath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/temp/"+TEMP_PHOTO_FILE;
                System.out.println("path "+filePath);
                Bitmap selectedImage =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                bitmapdrawable = new BitmapDrawable(selectedImage);
                generator_imagen.setImageDrawable(bitmapdrawable);
                app_gestorVistas("GENERATE");
                app_posicionGrid=9999;
            }
        }
    }}
```

This is the function:

```
public void loadfromgallery(){  //TODO LOAD FROM GALLERY
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);
}
private Uri getTempUri() {
    return Uri.fromFile(getTempFile());
}

private File getTempFile() {
    if (isSDCARDMounted()) {
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/temp/"+TEMP_PHOTO_FILE);

        try {f.createNewFile();}
        catch (IOException e) {}
        return f;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private boolean isSDCARDMounted(){
    String status = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (status.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        return true;
    return false;
}



private static final String TEMP_PHOTO_FILE = "mprt_img.jpg";
```

This is my filtered logcat (Lifecycle)

```
   01-27 13:34:29.476: V/EVENTO(4630): STATE:  onCreate
01-27 13:34:36.261: V/EVENTO(4630): STATE:  onStart
---APP BUSY--
01-27 13:34:47.296: V/EVENTO(4630): STATE:  onStop
--STOP APP AN DSHOW IMAGEPICKER---
01-27 13:35:01.316: V/EVENTO(4630): STATE:  onRestart
01-27 13:35:01.332: V/EVENTO(4630): STATE:  onStart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your logcat output?

What is your **TEMP_PHOTO_FILE**? What's the life cycle of your main activity? When you come back from image picker, does it invoke onCreate again? If so, you lose all your temporary variable, and you should save them in the bundle.

```
    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  if (filesaved == null) {
    outState.putString("file-uri", "");
  }
  else {
    outState.putString("file-uri", filesaved.toString());
  }
};
```

---

Another problem could be the creation of the file. Make sure the folder exist!

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

File dir = new File (sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/temp/");

dir.mkdirs();

File file = new File(dir, TEMP_PHOTO_FILE);

...

FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: HI,
private static final String TEMP_PHOTO_FILE = "mprt_img.jpg";

I don't know if the picker invokes onCreate.How i can see and modify??
Thank you

Comment: Insert a log on every state of the life cycle. oncreate, onpause, ondestroy etc and see if the oncreate is called again when you come back from the picker. What's the problem or logcat with android >4.0?

Comment: This is my logcat "filtered" lifecycle

01-27 13:34:29.476: V/EVENTO(4630): STATE:  onCreate
01-27 13:34:36.261: V/EVENTO(4630): STATE:  onStart (BUSY)
01-27 13:34:47.296: V/EVENTO(4630): STATE:  onStop   (STOP APP and load ImagePicker)
01-27 13:35:01.316: V/EVENTO(4630): STATE:  onRestart(CROP FINISHED)
01-27 13:35:01.332: V/EVENTO(4630): STATE:  onStart

Comment: maybe your app failes at this point: try {f.createNewFile();}
        catch (IOException e) {}. If it's unable to create the file, you return the same file (that does not exist). Try to catch the exception and do something else, or add a log in this case.

Comment: It's true!! I forgot to check if directory exist in this function (It creates in "savetosd" function.